# parbox vertical alignment

Tags: vertical-alignment, boxes

The following code uses parboxes and hrules to vertically align two rectangles of different heights.  The hrule seem a bit hackish to me.  Is there a more elegant solution?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{4in}   
\parbox[t]{2cm}{\hrule height 0pt width 0pt \rule{1cm}{1cm}} 
\parbox[t]{2cm}{\hrule height 0pt width 0pt \rule{1cm}{3cm}}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

My apologies. I tried to simplify the problem and only obfuscated it. The real problem is vertical alignment of two figures, each created in separate Tikz environments. I would like the y's to be at the same height, but I'd like to accomplish this outside of tikz.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture} 
\draw (0,0)--(0,1) node[above]{$y$};  
\end{tikzpicture} 

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0)--(0,3) node[above]{$y$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want to align black boxes or other objects?

Comment: Why don't you post your tikz code directly?

Comment: Still it is not clear. Do you have two tikzpicutres? I it is only one try with `\draw (0,0)--(0,1) node[above]{$y$};
\draw (1,-2)--(1,1) node[above]{$y$};`

Comment: @HarishKumar Please see my edited comment above - there are two tikzpictures. The solution by Steven B. Segletes using the stackengine package is appreciated.  Do you have a solution that does not require additional packages?

Comment: @steven_nevets: I feel that setting the baselines within the `tikzpicture` is more elegant. However you can use `\parbox[t]{2cm}{\null \begin{tikzpicture}...}` for both pictures.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{4in}   
\parbox[t]{2cm}{\rule[-1cm]{1cm}{1cm}} 
\parbox[t]{2cm}{\rule[-3cm]{1cm}{3cm}}
\end{minipage}

or simpler

\begin{minipage}[t]{4in}   
\rule[-1cm]{1cm}{1cm}\hspace{1cm}%
\rule[-3cm]{1cm}{3cm}
\end{minipage}



\end{document}
```

Comment: That's a good question.  I actually want to align tikz figures whose heights are not readily identified.  Unfortunately, that renders the negative vertical compensations unhelpful.  Any advise?

Comment: @steven_nevets For something like Tikz don't you always know the height? As always, it really helps if you post a complete document that demonstrates the real problem.

Answer (score 3):

Just name the two nodes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(T1.base)]
\draw (0,0)--(0,1) node[above](T1){$y$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(T2.base)]
\draw (0,0)--(0,3) node[above](T2){$y$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document} 

\belowbaseline[0pt]{%
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\draw (0,0)--(0,1) node[above]{$y$};  
\end{tikzpicture} 
}
\belowbaseline[0pt]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0)--(0,3) node[above]{$y$};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]